# How extract waypoint route from bing maps directions and convert it to a shapefile

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, arcgis, shapefile

I was wondering if it is possible to extract each waypoint route in bing maps directions (example of waypoint routes below)

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15387358/bing%20route.jpg

The only way i know how to extract the route is through this method:

www.elsewhere.org/journal/gmaptogpx/

and then use this to convert to a shapefile:

freegeographytools.com/2007/exporting-gps-data-to-gis-i-garmin-gps-units

My problem is that the above method only works on google maps and the calculated route in google maps is different from bing maps.  My only workaround as of now (very tedious) is to manually trace the route out in google maps by dragging wapoints to match the route from bing maps.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this article a couple of years ago explaining how to create a mini- Windows App that connected to the Bing Maps routing service and created a WKT Linestring from the output for import into SQL Server: http://www.viawindowslive.com/Articles/VirtualEarth/CreatingRoutesinSQLServer2008usingVE.aspx

It wouldn't be too hard to adapt this to create a shapefile of the route instead. (Or alternatively, just take the WKT output and convert it to a shapefile using OGR2OGR (http://www.gdal.org))

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have been trying to get your code to work but I'm unable to get the url that was provided to add the token service.  I ended up using this this url http://staging.mappoint.net/standard-30/mappoint.wsdl and which listed the CommonService class.

Comment: The errors in the code say that all the service references added do not exist in the namesapce VESQLRouteGeneratorApp.